# Create a variable in SPSS using 2 other variables?

Tags: variables, spss

So, I've been using SPSS for not so long and I need help creating a variable using two others.

I have a survey, and a variable of "household number" for each person and another variable of "relationship with household head" (head=1, spouse=2, child=3 etc).
I want to create a variable of "type of family" by using the relationship with household head in each household.

So, something like:

```
If in the household there's only the head, then is 1
If there's the head, spouse and/or children, then is 2
If it's head plus any other type of relative, it's 3.
```

Eg:

> Household Nº - Relationship
>
> 1            -     1
>
> 1            -     2
>
> 1            -     3

In the household "1" there is a head (1), a spouse (2) and a child (3), so it would be a "type of family" 2.

I don't know what commands to use for doing this is SPPS. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this will require the use of `AGGREGATE` to assign needed characteristics to all family members and then use of if statements to make the family types. So lets start with some example data similar to yours. This makes a set of families in long format.

```
data list free / house relation.
begin data
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
3 1
3 2
4 1
4 3
5 1
5 2
5 3
5 3
5 3
end data.
VALUE LABELS relation
1 'Head'
2 'Spouse'
3 'Child'.
```

From here I will suggest four types of families; `Single-No Children`, `Couple-No Children`, `Single-With Children`, and `Couple-With Children`. To get these, I make a dummy variable to indicate whether a case is a child or a spouse, and then aggregate the minimum value within family to provide a flag for if the family has any spouse or any child.

```
*Make flag for if have a spouse and if have a child.
COMPUTE child = (relation EQ 3).
COMPUTE spouse = (relation EQ 2).
*Aggregate to get a flag for child or spouse.
AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES
  /BREAK=house
  /AnyChild = MAX(child) 
  /AnySpouse = MAX(spouse)
  /NumChild=SUM(child)
  /TotalFamSize=N.
```

I also show how one can get the total number of children using `SUM` and the total family size using `N` in the aggregate command. From here you can use a series of if statements to categorize the different types of families.

```
*From here can make several fam categories using DO IF.
DO IF TotalFamSize = 1.
  COMPUTE FamType = 1.
ELSE IF AnySpouse = 1 AND AnyChild = 0.
  COMPUTE FamType = 2.
ELSE IF AnySpouse = 0 and AnyChild = 1.
  COMPUTE FamType = 3.
ELSE IF AnySpouse = 1 and AnyChild = 1.
  COMPUTE FamType = 4.
END IF.
VALUE LABELS FamType
1 'Single - No Children'
2 'Couple - No Children'
3 'Single - Children'
4 'Couple - Children'.
EXECUTE.
```

This logic of using aggregate to get statistics for the whole family should be amenable to whatever types of stats you want to generate.